# TO_JSON on anonymous struct in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

When doing `TO_JSON(struct)` on an anonymous struct, such as `(1,2,3)`, it treats all keys as empty string, and so it chops off all values after the first. For example:

```
SELECT val, TO_JSON(val) FROM UNNEST([(1,2,3)]) as val
```

[image]

Is there a way to get some generic key value or something, similar to what BigQuery renders in the UI, even if by an alternative method? The only other way I see to get it into json is to manually parse the format string (!!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first immediate option for this task would be to use the `STRUCT` operator, and assign manually the aliases. Main drawback of this solution is that you need to hardcode manually aliases of your table.

```
SELECT val, TO_JSON(val) 
FROM UNNEST([STRUCT(1 AS a, 
                    2 AS b,
                    3 AS c)]) as val
```

which gives:

| val. a | val. b | val. c | f0_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3} |

---

One solution that abstracts from assigning the aliases manually, yet allowing you to retrieve all the values of your original struct, is using `TO_JSON_STRING` in place of `TO_JSON`.

```
SELECT val, TO_JSON_STRING(val) 
FROM UNNEST([(1,2,3)]) as val
```

which gives:

| val. _field_1 | val. _field_2 | val. _field_3 | f0_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | {"":1,"":2,"":3} |

Comment: the second one is fine, and together with using `FORMAT("%T, value)` you can construct the value though it's a bit painful.